# Laravel Eloquent setting a default value for a model relation?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have two models:

```
class Product extends Eloquent {

    ...

    public function defaultPhoto()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Photo');
    }

    public function photos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Photo');
    }
}

class Photo extends Eloquent {

    ...

    public function getThumbAttribute() {
        return 'products/' . $this->uri . '/thumb.jpg';
    }

    public function getFullAttribute() {
        return 'products/' . $this->uri . '/full.jpg';
    }

    ...

}
```

This works fine, I can call `$product->defaultPhoto->thumb` and `$product->defaultPhoto->full` and get the path to the related image, and get all photos using `$product->photos` and looping through the values.

The problem arises when the product does not have a photo, I can't seem to figure out a way to set a default value for such a scenario.

I have tried doing things such as

```
public function photos() 
{
    $photos = $this->hasMany('Photo');
    if ($photos->count() === 0) {
        $p = new Photo;
        $p->url = 'default';
        $photos->add($p);
    }

    return $photos;
}
```

I have also creating a completely new `Collection` to store the new `Photo` model in, but they both return the same error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::getResults()
```

Has anyone done anything similar to this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would not put that kind of behavior in the model. I would simply use - if ( $product->photo === null ) { do something } - in the controller/view.

Comment: If you want to apply default values for these items, isn't it better done at the database level?  This will allow for consistent handling of NULL situations.

Comment: I resorted to doing the following in the view: `{{ $product->defaultPhoto ? $product->defaultPhoto->thumb : '/img/default-product.png'  }}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create an accessor on the Product model that did the check for you. Works the same if you just wanted to define it as a method, also (good for if you want to abstract some of the Eloquent calls, use an interface for your Product in case you change it later, etc.)

```
/**
 * Create a custom thumbnail "column" accessor to retrieve this product's
 * photo, or a default if it does not have one.
 * 
 * @return string
 */
public function getThumbnailAttribute()
{
    $default = $this->defaultPhoto;

    return ( ! is_null($default))
        ? $default->thumb
        : '/products/default/thumb.jpg';
}
```

You might also want to look into [Presenters](https://github.com/ShawnMcCool/laravel-auto-presenter). A bit overkill for some situations, but incredibly handy to have (and abstract things like this away from your models).

Comment: This! The answer was in my question (I already used accessors in the photo model!)