# Assign object to object/array in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Long time reader, first time asker. I'm experienced with things like Java/C but PHP is new to me.

I'm having an issue where an assignment doesn't assign to where I'd expect it to.

I'm getting an array from a MySQL database via Eloquent methods, in particular:

```
$result= TableA::where('tableA.id', '=', $id)
            ->with('tableB.tableC')
            ->get();
```

For reference, printing $result out looks like this:

```
[{"id":105, /*TableA fields*/, "tableB":null},
{"id":106, /*TableA fields*/, "tableB":null},
{"id":107, /*TableA fields*/, "tableB":{/*tableB fields*/, "tableC":
{"id":104, /*TableC fields*/}}},
{"id":108, /*TableA fields*/, "tableB":{/*tableB fields*/, "tableC":
{"id":105, /*TableC fields*/}}}]
```

In some cases a TableA tuple will have an associated record in tableB and hence tableC, other times there isn't an associated record in tableB. If there isn't an associated record I want to go through and make a temporary "dummy" record to pass through instead of passing through null. The code I'm using to do so is:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($result); $i++) 
{
    if($result[$i]["tableB"] == null)
    {
        Log:info($result); //Print line A
        $result[$i]["tableB"] = OtherController::makeDummyTableB(); //Assignment line
        Log::info($result); //Print line B
        Log::info($result[$i]["tableB"]); //Print line C
    }
}
```

The problem is that the assignment line doesn't assign to the "tableB" field in the object/array returned in $result. Printing $result out at print line A and B gives the same result, with "tableB" being null for the first two records. Print line C however gives the output I'm expecting, which is the dummy record I'm creating

```
{"tableC":{/*TableC fields*/}}
```

So the assignment is doing *something*, but it's not assigning to the field in $result that's already there, and instead is assigning it to somewhere else (That doesn't show up when I attempt to display it)

If anyone could let me know what my current code is actually doing, and how to have it do what I'm expecting (replace `"tableB":null` with `"tableB":{"tableC":{/*TableC fields*/}}` ) it'd be much appreciated

Comment: `tableB` and `tableC` are relations in your Eloquent model. You can only correctly assign to these by using the [relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships) methods. It also looks like you're assigning the value based on working with an array, rather than an Eloquent instance.

Comment: What is $j in your $result array key, have you initialise that to "0"??

Comment: @Rits it's a typo, I've just edited it now. Should have been $i

Comment: You can use accessor for the tableB relation in tableA model. See the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20715380/1561146

Comment: Is `tableB` a `HasOne` or `BelongsTo` relationship, or is something else?

Comment: @patricus It's a `hasOne` relationship

Comment: Are you on Laravel >= 5.3?

Comment: @patricus I'm on Laravel 5.4.8 to be precise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eloquent models have a lot of "magic" going on in the background. The fields from the table are loaded into an `attributes` property, and the relationships are loaded into a `relations` property.

The issue you're running into is that `tableB` is a relationship field, not a table field. Its data is stored in the `relations` property. The `relations` property, however, is not directly modifiable the way you are attempting. When you attempt to modify it using `$result[$i]["tableB"]`, that code is actually modifying the `tableB` field in the `attributes` property.

Then there is the issue of getting the data. When you attempt to read the data directly using `$result[$i]["tableB"]`, it will first look in the `attributes` property, and if it isn't found there, then it will look in the `relations` property.

However, when you dump the entire object using `Log::info($result);`, any data in the `relations` property overwrites the data in the `attributes` property. So, after a direct assignment using `$result[$i]["tableB"] = 'asdf'`, `Log::info($result)` will not show the change (since `relations` overwrites `attributes`), whereas `Log::info($result[$i]["tableB"])` will show the change (since it looks at `attributes` first).

So, analyzing your code, we have:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($result); $i++) {
    if($result[$i]["tableB"] == null) {
        // At this point:
        // - tableB relation is null
        // - tableB attribute does not exist

        // This is a full dump, so the relations overwrites the attributes.
        // tableB will show null
        Log:info($result);

        // After this assignment executes:
        // - tableB relation will be null
        // - tableB attribute will be the dummy object
        $result[$i]["tableB"] = OtherController::makeDummyTableB();

        // This is a full dump, so relations (null) overwrites the attributes (dummy object).
        // tableB will show null
        Log::info($result); //Print line B

        // This is direct access, which accesses attributes (dummy object) before relations (null).
        // tableB will show dummy object
        Log::info($result[$i]["tableB"]); //Print line C
    }
}
```

If you really want to go about it this way, you should use the `setRelation()` method:

```
$result[$i]->setRelation('tableB', OtherController::makeDummyTableB());
```

That will specifically set `tableB` on the `relations` property, which is what you're trying to do. That should get everything working for you.

---

Having said that, you may be able to tackle this a different way. If you're using Laravel >= 5.3 and your `tableB` relationship is a HasOne (5.3+) or a BelongsTo (5.4+) relationship, you can use the `withDefault()` functionality on the relationship so that it will automatically generate a default model when one does not exist in the database. You can read more about this [in the documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#default-models).

So, your relationship definition would look something like:

```
public function tableB()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\TableB')->withDefault();
}
```

Now, when no `tableB` record exists, the relationship will load with a new empty `TableB` object, instead of `null`.

If you need something more than just an empty `TableB` object, you can pass a function to the `withDefault()` method, and that function will be used to generate the default object.

Comment: Oops, yeah that's a typo. Thanks for spotting it, I'll edit ithe post now

Comment: @Blacklles I have added a little more explanation on both parts. It can be pretty confusing without diving into the source code.

Comment: Perfect, this explains a lot of what I'd been running into whilst trying to debug this myself - Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent does not return a plain PHP array, when using the `get` method it will return an instance of `Illuminate\Support\Collection` and you cannot simply assign an object like that into a `Collection`. To do so, you have to convert the collection to an array first:

```
$result = TableA::where('tableA.id', '=', $id)
        ->with('tableB.tableC')
        ->get();

// Convert collection to array
$result = $result->toArray();

for ($i=0; $i < count($result); $i++) 
{
    if($result[$i]["tableB"] == null)
    {
        Log:info($result); //Print line A
        $result[$i]["tableB"] = OtherController::makeDummyTableB(); //Assignment line
        Log::info($result); //Print line B
        Log::info($result[$i]["tableB"]); //Print line C
    }
}
```

Now you should have your value correctly assigned.

Comment: As the `toArray()` method alludes to, this will convert all the objects inside the collection to arrays. They will no longer be Eloquent models, but plain arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
foreach ($result as $whatever) 
{
    if($whatever->tableB == null)
    {
        $whatever->tableB = OtherController::makeDummyTableB();
    }
}
```

The problem is that you can't assign a tableB object to a array field of your tableA model...
Your tableB model most likely (I assume, depends how you built it) is related to your tableA model via a "tableB_id" field. So if you use your assignment, you end up with

```
$tableA["tableB_id"] //id of the related tableB, in your case null
$tableA["tableB"] //your newly assigned model, which has nothing to do with your relationship, because that should work on tableB_id
```

Just don't use weird array syntax for relations

Comment: For Eloquent models, both the arrow syntax (`->tableB`) and the array syntax (`['tableB']`) call the same underlying method (`getAttribute()`). `$whatever->tableB = 'asdf';` is the same as `$whatever['tableB'] = 'asdf';` when `$whatever` is an Eloquent model.

Comment: If you wanna get tableB, you are correct. If you wanna set it, it's not the same...

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my original comment (meant `setAttribute()`). However, the statement still stands. Both methods call the underlying `setAttribute()` method. Arrow syntax goes through `__set()` magic method to call `setAttribute()`, and array syntax goes through `offsetSet()` method to call `setAttribute()`.